# Integrate java app installed through flathub to GTK

Tags: java, theme, flatpak

I have installed sweethome3d via flathub(https://flathub.org/apps/com.sweethome3d.Sweethome3d). Expectedly, the look is not integrated with Adwaita or whatever GTK theme and icons I am using.

Is there any way to make the java apps installed via flathub to use:

- Shell theme (dark)
- My icon theme (installed in my ~/.themes or ~/.local/share/themes)?

I am using gnome 45 as it comes with f39.